# How to disable editing options, except for the backspace, of JDateChooser?

Tags: java, swing, jdatechooser

I am using JdateChooser to take input from the user. I wanted to disable editing options for the textfield that appears except for the backspace. I used the following code

```
JDateChooser chooser = new JDateChooser();
JTextFieldDateEditor editor = (JTextFieldDateEditor) chooser.getDateEditor();
editor.setEditable(false);
```

but this disables all the options including the backspace.

Comment: If everything but the backspace is disabled, there is no way to enter anything anymore.

Comment: A JDateChooser component consists of a small button using which date can be selected and a small text field that displays the selected date. I'm talking about that text field.